# Accessing a jobjectarray in C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_beantowngameshop_bingoshoot_api_ApslarHandler_sendEvent
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobjectArray);
```

The jobjectArray is  object array of my java class that has two attributes

1) A String
2) A Integer

I want to iterate and read the values of this array ? Can anyone please show me how ?